# MariaDB: User defined attributes with Dynamic Columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to put together some pieces when it comes to my current task to allow the user to create some User Defined Fields.

While doing my research I came across the `Dynamic Columns` feature of MariaDB.
Has anyone got a use case for the latter and how they have been benefited from that?

If that's not a recommendable solution for User Defined fields, what are your thoughts on EAV(Entity-Attribute-Value Implemetation) pattern?

```
[ITEM]
======
id 
name
attributeId
languageId

[ITEM_DESCRIPTIONS]
==================
id
itemID
description
languageId
```

Comment: You mean [Dynamic Columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dynamic-columns/)?

Comment: @stickybit Indeed! Thanks for the correction. Any experience with the latter?

Comment: I think it depends what these user-defined fields will be used for. Are you going to search or filter on these fields? What kind of values would typically be stored in them? In your table outlines above, where are the user-defined fields?

Comment: My opinion on EAV:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav